# Capitalization of for latin phrase in title case (in vitro, in vivo, etc)

Tags: capitalization, titles, headline-case

I would like to use the following phrase as a title that needs to be in "title case". I'm wondering what the procedure is for capitalizing Latin phrases.

> Media for in vitro tissue production

Variation 1

> Media for in Vitro Tissue Production

Variation 2

> Media for In Vitro Tissue Production

Comment: Title case varies from one style guide to another.  Do you know which style guide you need to follow?

Comment: The Chicago Manual of Style explicitly mentions that Latin expressions such as "in vitro" should be capitalized in headline style.